# Using $scope.$apply() outside of the AngularJS world

Tags: angularjs

I have created jQuery widget that basically adds more functionality and CSS stylings to the native jQuery UI Datepicker.  I use the `onSelect` option for the datepicker to update the `<input>` accordingly. The problem is that even though the input changes, the model on the $scope does not change.  I know I need to use $scope.$apply() in some way to notify angular that the input has changed.

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
this.options.onSelect = function (dateText, inst) {


                $el.val(dateText);
                that.$scope.$apply(); // This isn't working. I think I need to do something else
                that.wrap.hide();


                jQuery(document).find('.iconalt').hide();


                if (that.options.afterSelect !== undefined) {
                    that.options.afterSelect();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This has got to be a very common problem... correct? How does no one know? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you set value using `$el.val(dateText);` your ngModel does not change and you dont even need `that.$scope.$apply();` in this case. I guess you need to update the model and then do scope.apply()

Comment: if you really need to modify the DOM, create a custom angular directive. also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: I am using an Angular Directive called my-datepicker.. that is where I bind the element to the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution. I needed to update the model before calling $apply()

```
this.options.onSelect = function (dateText, inst) {


                $el.val(dateText);
                that.$scope.date = dateText; // Adding this worked
                that.$scope.$apply(); 
                that.wrap.hide();


                jQuery(document).find('.iconalt').hide();


                if (that.options.afterSelect !== undefined) {
                    that.options.afterSelect();
                }
            }
```